# Processing Group of File in Spring Integeration

Tags: java, ftp, spring-batch, spring-integration

We have a requirement in our project.Where we need to pool a Group of file from FTP server and process that as a group in order.Say user will put 2 files - ProjectFile and ProjectRelationFile(they will put in any order but they will put these 2 files).i need to process ProjectFile first and then ProjectRelationFile.

How i can achieve this is Spring Integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one way do achieve that - use [`<resequencer>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#resequencer). All your files in group should accept the same `correlationId`. You can use `release-partial-sequences="true"`, of course. In addition you should provide `sequenceNumber` header to determine the `order` of your message to release.